# How to add IMAGE to rendering extensions?

Tags: windows-7, rendering, activex

I have a problem with one ActiveX. The main problem is that I can't print from the internet, since our Group Policies restrict the installation from normal users. I have created a snippet to install this activeX from Configuration Manager. It works ok, however I still can't print.

Looking on the internet I found two sites that are helping me, however there is a step I don't know how to do:

> You do not mention having Image rendering in your available extensions. Make sure that you have Image in your rendering extensions. Print uses EMF, which is part of Image.

```
<Extension Name="IMAGE" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.ImageRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering"/>
```

How do I do that? How do I add Image to my rendering extensions?

Thanks for your help!

**FIX:**

I found where I have to add that extension.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx

I hope this works for anyone else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where I have to add that extension.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx

Once the dll is registered in the machine, then you have to add this format to you sql server.

I hope this works for anyone else...